# Running AWS Lambda for multiple parameters one at a time

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am new to working with AWS and I have created a web scraping python script that works with a third party API to serve requests. The function pulls posts and comments from a forum based platform and I am trying to run the function on AWS lambda. I have a dictionary of multiple forum names and the function iterates through the dictionary to execute the function for one forum at a time. It then stores the scraped data directly into S3.
The problem is that the execution time is too much and the function barely scrapes one forum and the maximum lambda execution time (15 minutes) is reached.
I am looking for a solution in which the function runs again every 30 minutes with a different forum name as the event parameter until all the forums in the dictionary are passed.
Any ideas on how this may be done?

I tried pairing the main lambda function with another one which would invoke it with different parameters every time and this "runner" function would be scheduled to run every 30 minutes but no success.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/?step-functions.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&step-functions.sort-order=desc). It's really perfect for something like this. You could run multiple instances of the lambda at once (one for each site) using the `Map` state, or you could run it in a loop, as you described, using the `Wait` state to pause it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I'll give that a try.